# ASP.net Session state fail over on cluster

Tags: asp.net, session

I am just started working on session modes, but after spending some hours found some doubts which I couldn't found by google search.. hope I will get expertise advice/solution here..

We have three servers 192.xxx.xxx.A, 192.xxx.xxx.B, 192.xxx.xxx.C respectively (clusters) with NLB (hardware) where our application will be deployed, earlier I created a test website to check session state fail over, below is code for mentioned test website.

ASPX:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestCluster.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestCluster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test Cluster</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>Test Cluster</h1>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSession" runat="server" Text="Session Test" 
            onclick="btnSession_Click"/>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In above code I only have one button and on button click my HTTP request will be initiate.

ASPX.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;


public partial class TestCluster : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    static string seesionTest = "";
    static int counterAlive = 0;
    static int counterdDead = 0;
    static int isPostBackCounter = 0;
    static string IspostBack = "";
    System.IO.StreamWriter file;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["activeSession"] = "Session is Alive";

            isPostBackCounter = isPostBackCounter + 1;
            if (isPostBackCounter > 1)
            {
                IspostBack = "PostBack Happened";
            }
        }

    }
    protected void btnSession_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long lg = 0;
        btnSession.Enabled = false;
        for (; ; )
        {
            lg++;
            if (lg == 9223372036)
            {
                btnSession.Enabled = true;
                break;
            }
            httpProcessStart();
        }
    }

    protected void httpProcessStart()
    {
        file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("e:\\log.txt");
        file.WriteLine("httpProcessStart called.");
        try
        {
            file.WriteLine("Session-"+Session["activeSession"].ToString());
            if (Session["activeSession"] != null && Session["activeSession"].ToString() != "")
            {
                file.WriteLine("activeSession");
                seesionTest = "";
                counterAlive = counterAlive + 1;
                string compName = "Response coming from " + System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");
                seesionTest += "<br>" + counterAlive + ":" + Session["activeSession"].ToString() + " ";
                string text = "";
                if (IspostBack != null && IspostBack != "")
                {
                    text = seesionTest + ", " + "  " + IspostBack + ",  " + "  " + compName;
                }
                else
                {
                    text = seesionTest + ",  " + " " + compName;
                }
                string lines = text + DateTime.Now + "\r\n";
                file.WriteLine(lines);
                file.Flush();
                file.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                file.WriteLine("sessionDead");
                btnSession.Enabled = false;
                counterdDead = counterdDead + 1;
                string seesionDead = "Session is dead restart application";
                string text = "";
                text = seesionDead;
                string lines = text + DateTime.Now + "\r\n";
                file.WriteLine(lines);
                file.Flush();
                file.Close();
                counterAlive = 0;
            }


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

web.config

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="20" stateConnectionString="tcpip=xxx.xxx.xxx.B:42424">
```

As mentioned above we have three servers so i used server B to store session state..
Provided code is tested and working fine but here is one doubt, what will be the IP (stateConnectionString="tcpip=?") if NLB is established either we use virtual IP of NLB or any other IP? and if use virtual IP of NLB where will be session is going to store?